# Why does this ActionScript 3 code not draw a line?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5

I am trying for a minimal program that can draw a line, in a new Flex project (using Flash Builder 4.6):

But when it is run in a web browser (Chrome or Firefox), and the button `myButton` is clicked on, no line is drawn -- does anybody know how to make it work, and how to make it so that it will draw without needing to click on the button?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here --> 
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>

        <![CDATA[

            public function drawLine():void 
            {
                var canvas:Shape = new Shape();
                canvas.graphics.lineStyle(3, 0xff);
                canvas.graphics.moveTo (0,0);
                canvas.graphics.lineTo(300,300);
                this.addChild(canvas);
            }

        ]]>

    </fx:Script>

    <s:Button label="myButton" click="drawLine()" />

</s:Application>
```

Comment: You might try a Spark [SpriteVisualElement](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/core/SpriteVisualElement.html) or [Graphic](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/primitives/Graphic.html) instead of Shape,

Comment: Is using Shape possible?  In Essential ActionScript 3.0 by O'Reilly, p. 630, it uses Shape, but just that it doesn't have a complete program listing

Comment: Well, your Shape does not have any height or width specified.  I don't believe that shapes have code to automatically size themselves.

Comment: so if I use `canvas.width = 300;` and `canvas.height = 300;` right after `canvas` is created, it is the same...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A much easier way to draw a simple line (or more complex lines too, if you wish) in a Flex application, is to use FXG graphics. This little snippet should draw the same line as in your example immediately when tha application starts up:

```
<s:Path data="M 0 0 L 300 300 Z">
    <s:stroke>
        <s:SolidColorStroke color="0xff" weight="3" />
    </s:stroke>
</s:Path>
```

Done!

Now if you absolutely wish to stick with the `Shape` class from your example (which I wouldn't recommend in a Flex app), you will need a way to add it to the displayList of a Spark Flex 4 app. `Shape` is not an `IVisualElement`, which is the only interface the `addElement()` method accepts.
You can use the [SpriteVisualElement](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/core/SpriteVisualElement.html) class, which serves exactly this purpose. Note that in an mx (Flex 3) application, you wouldn't need this because you could simply use the `addChild()` method. (I know this may be confusing for newcomers: it's a matter of backwards compatibility.)

```
private function drawLine():void {
    var shape:Shape = new Shape();
    shape.graphics.lineStyle(3, 0xff);
    shape.graphics.moveTo (0,0);
    shape.graphics.lineTo(300,300);

    var sve:SpriteVisualElement = new SpriteVisualElement();
    sve.addChild(shape);

    addElement(sve);
}
```

Now, to avoid the button click, just call `drawLine()` when the Application's creationComplete event fires:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
           minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
           creationComplete="drawLine()">
```

Comment: and just add `import spark.core.*` as well?  If you won't use `Shape` in a Flex app, would you use `Shape` in an ActionScript project?

Comment: @JeremyL I don't understand your `import` question. As for the other one: yes, use `Shape` in ActionScript projects and use FXG in Flex projects.

Comment: because if the `import` line isn't there, it would compile with an error: that `SpriteVisualElement` is not defined or something...

Answer (score 1):

The Spark Application tag extends SkinnableComponent which will throw a runtime error when using the AddChild() method.  Make sure that you have the Debug Version of the Flash Player installed so that you can see the error.  It'll help you in debugging a great many things.

Here is some code that works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here --> 
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>

        <![CDATA[

            public function drawLine():void 
            {
                drawingArea.graphics.lineStyle(3, 0x000000);
                drawingArea.graphics.moveTo (0,0);
                drawingArea.graphics.lineTo(300,300);
            }

        ]]>

    </fx:Script>

    <s:Button label="myButton" click="drawLine()" />


    <s:Group width="100%" height="100%" id="drawingArea">

    </s:Group>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

I gave the app it's own drawing area, in MXML, and drew to that area.  This is an AIR app; but the same code should work in a web based app.

Here is another sample, which does not create the drawing area in MXML; but ActionSCript:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here --> 
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>

        <![CDATA[
            import mx.core.UIComponent;

            public function drawLine():void 
            {
                var canvas :UIComponent = new UIComponent;
                canvas.graphics.lineStyle(3, 0xff);
                canvas.graphics.moveTo (0,0);
                canvas.graphics.lineTo(300,300);
                this.addElement(canvas);

            }

        ]]>

    </fx:Script>

    <s:Button label="myButton" click="drawLine()" />


</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Note; I used a UIComponent as the drawing element here.  I believe UIComponent is the "highest" component up the hierarchy chain which implements IVisualElement and can be passed into the addElement method.

Comment: both work... but is using `Shape` possible as in Essential ActionScript 3.0 by O'Reilly?  (also how can it draw the line without needing the button to invoke `drawLine()`?)

Comment: Yes, using Shape should be possible.  But, you'll have to wrap the shape in a Flex Container for use in a Flex Application.  ( Not a Spark Container).  Yes, you can draw a line without needing to click a button; you can execute the code anywhere.  Perhaps as part of an updateDisplayList() method, which is part of the Flex Component Lifecycle?